# Excel / Google Sheet - Condition IF .. BUT

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-2010

I'm looking for a formula on excel / google sheet that could calculate a "Final score inc. conditions" with **IF ... BUT...** and multiple conditions

*For example: IF someone have a type of diploma and a result of 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 in 4 differents clb skills, it will give a final score in a row "Final score inc. conditions" depending of diploma and 4 clb results.

**Practical example : if someone have a master degree and clb speaking : 9 , clb reading : 9, clb writing : 9, clb listening 7, it will give a Final score inc. conditions of **25**.

But if someone have a master degree and clb speaking : 9 , clb reading : 9, clb writing : 9, clb listening 9, it will give a Final score inc. conditions of **50**

Here some screenshots to understand more easily what i mean (including calculation rules).

Thank you in advance for your help.

[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXv3n.png)

[clb scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13yoy.png)

[calculation rules final score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Eucy.png)

Comment: You want AND...

Comment: ^^^ Usually this is done through `AND()`, however since you are interested in a range of values with a true median, you can simply apply: `=ABS(B2-17)<=1`

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help.

Comment: I see you edited the question. Is this the same issue as in the original question? It's not clear from my point of view what you want to accomplish here. Can you please provide more details? (a copy of the spreadsheet, not just screenshots, might be useful here).

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(AND(B2>=16,B2<=18),TRUE, FALSE)`

Works in Excel but not sure about Google Sheet

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help.